# jQuery UI destroy out of parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some squares where I put images in through draggable and droppable like this

```
<div class="mymaindiv">
    <div class="myimagetofill">
        <div class="myimage"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="myimagetofill">
      <div class="myimage"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="myimagetofill">
      <div class="myimage"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I do this

```
$('.myimagetofill').droppable({
    accept:'.spell',
    out: function(ev, ui){
        console.log($(this));
        if(ui.draggable.parent().prop('className').indexOf('myimagetofill') >= 0){
            ui.helper.off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function () {
                ui.draggable.remove();
            });
        }
    },
```

It works but when I go to a square next to my div, this is deleting it. I want to delete only if I bring the div "myimage" outside of the parent "mymaindiv". How can I do that?

EDIT :

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/174732/

When at the grey container, I want my draggable item to destroy ONLY if it is out of the grey thing or come back at it's original spot. Otherwise if you drag an element on an another it will deplace them...

I have a clue : the fact is that when I drop out it triggers the out and the drop evenement... I don't want to have the drop evenement triggered when I'm out.

Thanks

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect. You can only set `"mymaindiv"` to an attribute. It seems like you should have `<div class='mymaindiv'>`.

Comment: Corrected I just forgot it thanks!

Comment: Is `.indexOf('myimagetofill')` supposed to be `.indexOf('.myimagetofill')` (with a period for class name)? I'm not sure because I don't use jQuery UI

Comment: Yes I look for 'myimagetofill' string in this part

Comment: It'll be better to create demo/snippet

Comment: And by the way, why not use jQuery.hasClass() rather than the indexOf() hack? And perhaps set a droppable on myMainDiv itself?

Comment: According to the docs, that UI you refer to ought to be an empty object. How the heck is that actually doing anything?!

Comment: I created a demo and modify some things I found

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' there are so many issues I am not even sure where to begin. You're using `.find()` when you could be using proper selectors. The jQuery should be wrapped in `$(function(){})`... see what I can do.

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' please clarify what you want to have happen. When an item is dragged to a empty drop, it should accept it. If the item is dropped on a full drop area, do you want it to exchange or revert the drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get, what I believe, is the functionality that you are looking for, I had to rewrite a lot of stuff.

A working example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1cr7Lxu9/12/

**HTML**

```
<div class="backgrounding">
  <div class="stats-category">
    <div class="stats-content contain">
      <div class="fire spell">
        <i class="fas fa-fire fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="earth spell">
        <i class="fas fa-leaf fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="water spell">
        <i class="fas fa-tint fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="wind spell">
        <i class="fas fa-cloud fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats-header"><i class="fas fa-th-list fa-fw fa-sm"></i> Section 1</div>
    <div class="stats-content receive">
      <div class="spell-receiver empty"></div>
      <div class="spell-receiver empty"></div>
      <div class="spell-receiver empty"></div>
      <div class="spell-receiver empty"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Making use of FontAwesome to help give the parts some theme and feeling. Also setting up better classes can make things easier or better when it comes to the adding, moving, and removing of items.

**CSS**

```
.backgrounding {
  width: 310px;
  height: 240px;
}

.stats-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.stats-category {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.stats-header {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.stats-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fire {
  background-color: #ff6400;
}

.earth {
  background-color: #7f5f00;
}

.water {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.wind {
  background: #00bf00;
}

.stats-content.contain .spell {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  margin: 2px;
}

.stats-content.receive .spell {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

.spell i.fas {
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.spell-receiver {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 1px;
}

.spell-receiver .remove {
  z-index: 1001;
}

.spell-receiver.empty {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border: 1px dashed #a0a0a0;
}

.spell-receiver.filled {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.stats-content div.spell-receiver-border {
  border: 1px dashed #222;
  background: #a0a0a0;
}
```

A few minor additions and changes to make styling easier. Start with broad styles and then add some finer details.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function makeRecSpellDrag($o) {
    $o.draggable({
      containment: '.stats-content.receive',
      scope: 'drop',
      opacity: 0.65,
      revert: "invalid",
      zIndex: 1000,
      start: function() {
        console.log("EVENT: dragstart (Make Spell Drag)");
        $(this).parent().find("i.remove").remove();
      }
    });
  }

  function cleanEmpty() {
    $(".stats-content.receive .filled").each(function(ind, el) {
      if ($(el).children().length < 2) {
        $(el).removeClass("filled").addClass("empty");
        $(el).find("i.remove").remove();
      }
    });
    console.log("INFO: Clean Empty Completed.");
  }

  function receiveSpell($t, $s) {
    var $c = $s.clone();
    if ($s.hasClass("moveable")) {
      $c = $s.detach();
    }
    if ($t.hasClass("empty")) {
      console.log("INFO: Rec Spell.", $t, $c);
      $c.attr("style", "");
      $t.removeClass("empty").addClass("filled");
      $t.append($c);
      if (!$c.hasClass("moveable")) {
        $c.addClass("moveable");
        makeRecSpellDrag($c);
      }
      $("<i>", {
        class: "fas fa-times-circle fa-sm remove",
        title: "RemoveSpell"
      }).appendTo($t).position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left+8 top+8",
        of: $t
      }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("EVENT: click (Remove Item)");
        $t.empty();
        cleanEmpty();
      });
    } else {
      console.log("INFO: Rec Spell - Not Empty", $t);
      return false;
    }
  }

  $('.stats-content.contain .spell').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    scope: 'drop',
    containment: '.backgrounding',
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 1000
  });

  $('.stats-content.contain .spell').dblclick(function() {
    console.log("EVENT: doubleclick");
    var me = $(this).clone();
    if ($('.stats-content.receive .empty').length) {
      var target = $('.stats-content.receive .empty').eq(0);
      receiveSpell(target, me);
    }
  });

  $('.spell-receiver.empty').droppable({
    accept: '.spell',
    scope: 'drop',
    hoverClass: 'spell-receiver-border',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      console.log("EVENT: drop");
      var droppedItem;
      if (ui.draggable.hasClass("moveable")) {
        droppedItem = ui.draggable;
      } else {
        droppedItem = ui.helper;
      }
      if ($(this).is(".empty")) {
        // accept dropped item
        receiveSpell($(this), droppedItem);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
      cleanEmpty();
    }
  });
});
```

Since there are a lot of actions and processes you're going to repeat, I moved a lot of them into functions.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome help! I'll take all good practices you talked about to make my code cleaner and take some ideas of yours.

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' I hope it is helpful. If it is, I hope you feel like upvoting the answer and if it solves your issue, you might consider marking it as the answer.